# Where should I access nav_head_xyz content?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I used Android Studio's Navigation Drawer activity, and I want to place a dynamic spinner into the head (something like Google's Inbox).

Where should I set it up?

I try setting it up in `onCreate()`, using:

```
Spinner sp = (Spinner) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.nav_header_xyz,null).findViewById(R.id.MySpinner);
    String[] a = new String[]{"abc","xyz"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,a);
    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
    System.out.println(sp);
    sp.setAdapter(aa);

    navigationView.invalidate();
```

It runs, but doesn't change the spinner's content.

If I, on the other hand, set it up as:

```
Spinner sp = (Spinner)((NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view)).findViewById(R.id.MySpinner);
    String[] a = new String[]{"abc","xyz"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,a);
    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
    System.out.println(sp);
    sp.setAdapter(aa);

    navigationView.invalidate();
```

I get a NullPointerException on MySpinner.